# Add Active class by Load Component React

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React so i want to know how to add a Default Active Class. 
I have 3 li tag which is coming from a loop. On  load of the component i want to make first li active for the  li tag . When I click on 2nd li iam able to add active class using state.

```
 <li className={this.state.active == active ? " active" : ""} ></li>
```

So how can i add active class on load of component.

Comment: What is initial value in your state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your li's are rendered by a dedicated child component, you should lift the active state to the parent component (which generates li's). It would allow you to keep only one active li, and pass through props to li's their states and a reference to a state change callback.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62046832/2295549 for a similar use case.

If you have only one component involved, you should give id's to li's and hold a state like so :

```
const [activeId, setActiveId] = useState(firstId);

[...]

data.map(d => <li className={d.id === activeId ? 'active' : ''} onClick={(e) => setActiveId(d.id)}>...</li>
```