# Toggle two components using react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, toggle

I have two instances of the same component. The component can be opened or closed.

Component has `const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false)`

which is being set using useCallback

```
const openComponent = useCallback(() => {
    setIsOpen(true)
  }, [])

  const closeComponent = useCallback(() => {
    setIsOpen(false)
  }, [])
```

Components are within their own context. But I have trouble even coming up with an idea how to handle via parent, **when one instance opens, close the other** conundrum.

Passing state to parent and closing all of them before opening a new one is not an option.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why is lifting state up not an option?

Comment: Your requirements are at odds with each other. Either the parent needs to have control of the state, or the child does. Saying the parent needs to handle only one being open at once, but also saying the parent can't manage the state is not going to end well. There's probably a workaround with refs, but I wouldn't get in the habit of using refs to avoid better React patterns and practices.

Answer (score 2):

You should lift the state of these two components (open or false) to parent, so parent can have this logic (only one open at a time).

Parent should pass through props the open state to each children, along with a reference to a changeStateHandler(boolean) which children could call to notify the parent that they have been toggled.

So in parent you would have :

```
const [firstChildState, setFirstChildState] = useState(false);
const [secondChildState, setSecondChildState] = useState(false);

const handlStateChanged = () => {
  // toggle both states
}

[...]

<Child isOpen={firstChildState} onStateChange={handlStateChanged} />
<Child isOpen={secondChildState} onStateChange={handlStateChanged} />
```

In children :

```
// calls props.onStateChange on toggle, use props.isOpen to display proper state
```